# Python: Unpacking tuple into variables, arithmetic operation type error

Tags: python

I am trying to understand why there is type error in the following code:

```
from itertools import product
# -10 2 -1 for example as an input

nums = input()
a, b, c = [int(x) for x in nums.split()]

for c in product((-1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 1)):
    x, y, z = c
    if (x * a + y * b + z * c) == 13:
        print("Yes")
        break
else:
    print("No")
```

on (x * a + y * b + z * c) I get *"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'"*.
In debug x, y and z are indicated as (int) variables.
a, b and c are (int) as well. c is a tuple of (int). If all variables are of class (int) then why is that error?
Sorry for this post, a mistake.

Comment: "if all variables are of class int" - but they aren't, as you have said yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replace "c" in for loop to "t" as tuple, because there are two variables called c: first type of int and second type of tuple.

```
from itertools import product
# -10 2 -1 for example as an input

nums = input()
a, b, c = [int(x) for x in nums.split()]

for t in product((-1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 1)):
    x, y, z = t
    if (x * a + y * b + z * c) == 13:
        print("Yes")
        break
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: Please delete this post!